# SQL ... changing a having with a case into a where with a case

Tags: sql, teradata

This is my code.
The problem I have is related with the having.
I had to make some changes to handle a sas code in teradata, and, therefore, I needed to eliminate the GROUP BY and I have to use a WHERE clause rather than a HAVING, keeping the same conditions of it. Unfortunately, I am stucked and that's why I am asking for your suggestions.

```
SELECT t1.COD_PRODT, 
      t1.COD_RESID_, 
      t1.COD_DIVISA, 
      t1.COD_ABI, 
      t1.COD_NDG, 
      t1.COD_KTO, 
      t1.COD_PAESE, 
      t1.DAT_SCA, 
      t1.DAT_ACC, 
      t1.DAT_EST, 

      (COUNT(t1.COD_ABI)) AS COUNT_of_COD_ABI
  FROM WORK.A_VE_ES_DB_ANAGR_CONTO_CT_TT t1
  GROUP BY t1.COD_ABI,
           t1.COD_KTO
  HAVING  (
         CASE WHEN  COUNT_of_COD_ABI > 1 AND t1.DAT_EST IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                   WHEN COUNT_of_COD_ABI > 1 AND t1.DAT_EST IS NULL THEN 0
                   WHEN COUNT_of_COD_ABI = 1 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END
         ) = 1
  ORDER BY COUNT_of_COD_ABI DESC,
           t1.COD_ABI,
           t1.COD_KTO,
           t1.COD_NDG
```

I did something like that, but it turns out that it eliminates duplicates, while I need to bring them into analysis as well...

```
where (COUNT_of_COD_ABI = 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT_of_COD_ABI> 1 AND P2.DAT_EST IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN COUNT_of_COD_ABI> 1 AND P2.DAT_EST IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN COUNT_of_COD_ABI = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    end )
```

Can you help me out with this?

Comment: I must admit, I don't understand your query. You group by `COD_ABI, COD_KTO` and count rows, but you select many more columns. There are two options I see: (1)  `COD_ABI, COD_KTO` are unique in the table, so you simply select single rows with a count of 1. (2) `COD_ABI, COD_KTO` are not unique in the table and you cannot select the other columns without getting an exception. Neither makes sense. Are you showing the correct query? Can you explain what the table contains and what you are aggregating this to (i.e. what the combination `COD_ABI, COD_KTO` represents)?

Comment: You could nest your basic Select in a Derived Table/CTE and then apply WHERE, but why do you need that, what's the restriction in SAS? And your CASE can probably be simplified and rewritten as ORed-conditions: `where COUNT_of_COD_ABI = 1 or P2.DAT_EST IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Enrico . . . SAS `proc sql` supports both `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`, so I don't understand why you think you need to restructure the query.  I also can't tell if the code does what you want and you want to restructure it; or if it doesn't.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic are needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff basically the process is going from sas to TERADATA ... anyways, 
i made have been able to sort it out... I create a column into the select with 

`(Count(A.COD_ABI) Over (PARTITION BY A.COD_ABI, A.COD_KTO)) AS CC ` but now i have another problem

Comment: anyways thanks all